# Is it possible to create an ERD using an XL table like structure in Visio? I need to display columns (radio boxes) next to each attribute

Tags: entity, visio, erd, entity-relationship

[Here is an example of the Entity I wish to include. I have thought about dropping it into Visio as an Image, but I would like to retain the flexibility of keeping it as an embedded excel table, whilst making use of Visio's cardinality connectors. Thanks for any assistance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJsXH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing the point, the answer is trivial.
Insert the table as OLE object.
Copy the range in Excel, switch to Visio, paste special - excel.

If you want to glue connectors to the table, I better draw according connection points on the shape.

There are many other ways of drawing a table, but this one is certainly the simplest.